# Run another of the same stream

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Run another of the same stream..

so you can do?

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (isCancelled()) return null;
        getSignIns();

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/Sig", envelope);
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            sessionId = response.getProperty("sessionId").toString();

            androidHttpTransport=null;
            request=null;
            response=null;
            System.gc();

            getreport("1");
            Log.d("PGGURU", "*:sesid " + sessionId);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("PGGURU", "- error sess "+e.toString());

            dreplumclas drepluAsync = new dreplumclas(context,activity);
            drepluAsync.execute();

        }
    }

      return null;
    }
```

Sometimes this error comes
06-03 11:46:02.527: E/AndroidRuntime(9693): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
.....
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly is saying that you are trying to update the view from a different thread that is why you got the exception `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

I am guessing that it is coming from the `getreport("1");` if you want to update a view call the main thread and update it.

**example:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                \\this is where you update the view
            }
        });
```

where `runOnUiThread` is the method from the `Activity`. if you are in a fragment use the `getActivity().runOnUiThread` to call the activity instance.

Comment: may be due to the fact that I use doInBackground()publishProgress ?

error is not always!